# How can we write an annotation

Tags: java, annotations

I am very new to usage of annotation.
can anyone please tell me how can we declare an annotation and also call all the methods / variables that are declared with that annotation

am using java to implement this annotation

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface isAnnotatedVariable {
    String varName();
}
```

and used the annotation in

```
public class Example {

    @isAnnotatedVariable(varName = "S")
    public String var;
    @isAnnotatedVariable(varName = "S")
    public String var1;

}
```

and tried to get the variable names using

```
public class BuildStepClassDetector {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BuildStepClassDetector build = new BuildStepClassDetector();
        final Logger4J logger = new Logger4J(build.getClass().getName());
        final HashMap<String, Class<?>> isAnnotatedVariables = new HashMap<String, Class<?>>();
        final TypeReporter reporter = new TypeReporter() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public Class<? extends Annotation>[] annotations() {
                return new Class[] { isAnnotatedVariable.class };
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void reportTypeAnnotation(Class<? extends Annotation> arg0, String arg1) {
                Class<? extends isAnnotatedVariable> isAnnotatedVariableClass;
                try {
                    isAnnotatedVariableClass = (Class<? extends isAnnotatedVariable>) Class.forName(arg1);
                    isAnnotatedVariables.put(
                            isAnnotatedVariableClass.getAnnotation(isAnnotatedVariable.class).varName(),
                            isAnnotatedVariableClass);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    logger.getStackTraceString(e);
                }
            }
        };
        final AnnotationDetector cf = new AnnotationDetector(reporter);
        cf.detect();
        System.out.println(isAnnotatedVariables.keySet());

    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Which language you are working on? 2. What did you try .3. What is causing the problem? 4. What kind of annotation are you asking about?...simply...."Unclear of what you are asking"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example for declaring annotation and retrieving a annotated field using Reflection.

```
    package asif.hossain;

    import java.lang.annotation.*;
    import java.lang.reflect.Field;

    /**
     *
     * Created by sadasidha on 21-Aug-14.
     */
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.FIELD)
    @interface MyAnnotation {
        public String value();
    }
    class TestClass
    {
        @MyAnnotation("This is a name field")
        public String name;
    }
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String ... args) throws IllegalAccessException {
            TestClass testObject = new TestClass();
            Field[] fields = testObject.getClass().getFields();
            for (Field field : fields)
            {
                Annotation annotation = field.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
                if(annotation instanceof MyAnnotation)
                {
                    System.out.println(field.getName());
                    // get field value
                    String value = (String)field.get(testObject);
                   System.out.println("Field Value = "+ value);
                    //Set field value
                    field.set(testObject,"Your Name");
                    System.out.println(testObject.name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can follow this tutorial http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html to learn more about annotation and reflection.

Comment: if we want to use that field how can we do that? for example if i want to update 'name' how can we do that (i mean not directly updating name = "something")

Comment: field.get(testObject), field.set(testObject,"value") to get and set value. see my updated answer.